# Curly Brace notation for Full Adder Output

Tags: notation

My TA says that a common way of representing the output of addition using a full adder is:

{Cout, Out} = A + B+ Carry in

He says that this is equivalent to writing:

Out = a xor b xor carry in

Cout = A.B + Carry in . (A xor B)

What is the name of this notation? I want to look up more online, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: is this using a specific language? it looks like it might be a Tuple

Comment: No specific language. He wrote it down like it was some mathematical notation. I've tried looking online, but haven't been able to find a single source that uses it when they go over full adders.

Comment: if it's mathematical notation, better to ask on [Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)